# How to sort the scores obtained when the quiz is completed 3 times?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, alphabetical-sort

How would I sort scores obtained by a user when they take this quiz three times, from the highest score to lowest score? Also how would I sort the user names in alphabetical order, with their score next to their name when the code is run?

```
school_data = []
for x in range (0,3):
    quiz = dict()
    print ("Enter your name")
    quiz['name'] = input()
    print ("what class")
    quiz['class_code'] = input()

    print("1. 9+10=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 19:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong") 
    print("2. 16+40=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)
    if answer == 56:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")

    print("3. 5+21=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer) 
    if answer == 26:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")

    print("4. 5-6=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)
    if answer == -1:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")

    print("5. 21-9=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 12:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")
    quiz['score'] = score
    school_data.append(quiz)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the datastructure you're storing quiz results, scores and users in? The code for the quiz itself is not particularly relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your school_data list by score with

```
sorted_school_data = sorted(school_data, key=lambda k: k['score'])
```

This by default sorts with lowest score first, so from highest to lowest just do

```
sorted_school_data = sorted(school_data, key=lambda k: k['score'])[::-1]
```

To print out score and name you can do

```
for i in sorted(school_data, key=lambda k: k['name']):
    print('%s:%s' %(i['name'], i['score']))
```